# Showing column names in rows, Power BI report

Tags: excel, powerbi, report, multiple-columns, data-transform

at start I have this table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl67N.png)

From this data I've created this report (on the left table based on slicer placed at the right):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEOVA.png)

Is there a way to show it like that in Power BI (instead of showing column names horizontally I'd like to show it vertically):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67TNK.png)

I've tried pivoting/unpivoting columns and using headers as first row + transposing, but it seems like those solutions don't work because of column with companies names.

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Transform (in Power Query)
- Delete the company name column
- `Unpivot` all the columns
- `Group` by the `Attribute` column with the `Sum` operation

[image]